# Thread safe fast integer

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

So I have this `class` that holds 3 counters:

```
    public class Files
    {
        private static ObservableCollection<Files> _files = new ObservableCollection<Files>();
        private static int _inProcess;
        private static int _finished;
        private static int _inQueue;

        public static ObservableCollection<Files> List
        {
            get { return _files ; }
            set { _files = value; }
        }

        public static int InProcess
        {
            get { return _inProcess; }
            set
            {
                _inProcess = value;
            }
        }

        public static int Finished
        {
            get { return _finished; }
            set
            {
                _finished = value;
            }
        }

        public static int InQueue
        {
            get { return _inQueue; }
            set
            {
                _inQueue = value;
            }
        }
}
```

And from another class I want to add value to this fields:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref Files.InProcess);
```

But got this error:

> A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter.

This works fine:

```
Files.InProcess++;
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: ...so whats your question?

Comment: Why i cannot update this field ?

Comment: Fairly self explanatory.

Comment: So how can i update this field via different threads ?

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment(ref _inProcess);`

Comment: @DannyNitman You *really* need to know what you're doing if you want to write lock free multithreaded programs.  If you aren't *intimately* familiar with a lot of very complex rules around memory management in C# then you'll end up writing programs that don't work.

Comment: "Properties are not variables. They are methods, and cannot be passed to ref parameters." : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: @MongZhu I don't think it makes much since to protect a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty straightforward. You can't pass a property as ref. In this case the best option is to create a method

`public static void IncrementInProcess()
 {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _inProcess);
 }`

Comment: I can put this inside my Files class where _inProcess is member of this class ?

Comment: @DannyNitman Yes. While I'm at it, your properties are pretty pointless since the get and set are both public and no check is done in either case. You should either a) not use them at all or b) use auto-implemented properties